# Cannot get username in client MVC app

Tags: identityserver4

I have 2 projects, one is the identity server 4 and one is the client AspNetCore MVC.
On client app, how I can get the current user name or current user email ?
More specific, I would like to put it on _Layout.cshtml .

Thank you,
Mihai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a rest call to the server and have it return the authorized user.
Make sure you have the correct claims.

[Get current user name in IdentityServer4 & ASP.net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41356186/get-current-user-name-in-identityserver4-asp-net-core)

For the official docs to getting user info check here:
http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/endpoints/userinfo.html

Answer (score 0):

If your MVP app requests the scopes email and profile then these 2 properties should be available in the user claims (available through this.User.Claims in the MVC controller).